# Como dar um lock no TFS?

Tags: team-foundation-server

Estou usando o Team Foundation Server para trabalhar com um parceiro em um projeto C#
e estou com o seguinte problema:

Quando altero algum arquivo por exemplo "UsuarioController" e não dou *check in* o meu parceiro na máquina dele consegue alterar o mesmo arquivo. Quero conseguir configurar para acontecer da seguinte forma:

Quando alterar o arquivo UsuarioController na minha máquina e não der *check in* e o meu parceiro tentar alterar o mesmo arquivo, terá que aparecer uma mensagem para ele informando que o mesmo arquivo foi alterado por mim e só deixar ele alterar esse arquivo quando eu der *check in* na minha máquina.

Isso é possível?

---

@Brandão estava checado aqui como "Server", seguindo sua orientação alterei para Local(recommended) mas ainda continua os dois usuários conseguindo alterar o mesmo arquivo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quase isso. O nome da opção é <kbd>Check Out for Edit...</kbd>:

[image: TFS 1]

No *Lock Type*, escolha a opção **Chec In - Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in**:

[image: TFS 2]

Comment: Mas não tem como fazer algo automático, exemplo fiz a alteração automaticamente já faz o check out pra mim?

Comment: Tanto nas controller quanto no restante dos arquivos do projeto..

Comment: Serve para qualquer arquivo ou diretório do projeto. Suporta seleção de vários elementos (segurando Shift ou Ctrl e ir clicando).

Comment: e acredito que escolhendo a opção "Allow other users to check out but prevent them from checking in:" ira permitir que o parceiro altere o arquivo mas nao consiga dar check in isso? eu preciso que ele não consiga nem colocar uma virgula no arquivo enquanto eu não der check in..

Comment: Ah entendi então o correto é eu clicar nisso em todo meu projeto...

Comment: @RodolfoLaurenti Na verdade não alterar o arquivo era algo que tinha no VSS e não funcionava muito bem. No TFS a filosofia é um pouco diferente. Ele até pode alterar o arquivo, mas não pode enviar a modificação.

Comment: Mas toda vez que eu for querer bloquear um arquivo é obrigado em clicar "Check Out for Edit..." não tem como configurar para que isso seja automático? Exemplo: Abri o arquivo e alterei ele já fique bloqueado comigo

Comment: @RodolfoLaurenti Creio que não. Aliás, acho impossível algo assim funcionar.

Comment: Beleza, obrigado por tirar as dúvidas...

Answer (score 2):

Você quer trabalhar como o Visual Source Safe, não permitir que alguém faça check-out do arquivo enquanto estiver editando, é possível, mas não é uma boa prática, já que causa travamento no fluxo de trabalho. Mas se para o seu ambiente for bom, é possível habilitar essa feature seguindo os passos abaixo:

No Team Explorer, vá nas configurações do Team Project atual:

[image: Settings of Team Project]

Agora entre em configurações do versionador de código, lembrando que irá servir apenas para projeto que usa o TFVC e não Git:

[image: Source Control options]

Para alterar o comportamento e cada desenvolvedor ter exclusividade sobre o código em edição desmarque a caixa abaixo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando um desenvolvedor editar algum código o TFS irá bloquear a edição por outro, lembre-se de que, isso só irá ocorrer se o Workspace estiver configurado para Server, o que te dará outros prós e contras!

Comment: Brandão bom dia, isso não resolveu, testei agora cedo e não deu certo.. Ambos continua conseguindo alterar o arquivo.

Comment: Os 2 workspaces estão como Server?

Comment: Como vejo se está como Server?

Comment: No Team Explorer clica em Source Control Explorer, no menu da janela que abriu tem uma combobox, clica nela vai em Workspaces, seleciona o que você está usando, clica em Edit > Advanced; e você irá encontrar uma combo box Location: Sever/Local

Comment: Em "Workspace Settings" marquei a opção "Local (recommended)"
e continua ambos conseguindo alterar o mesmo arquivo...

Comment: Oque posso estar fazendo de errado?

Comment: A opção de Location deve ser Server

Comment: Fiz isso e continua do mesmo jeito Brandão..

Comment: O único jeito de travar o arquivo comigo é quando eu clico no item com o direito do mouse e clico em "Check Out for Edit". 
Mas fazer isso toda vez que for alterar um arquivo é complicado, pois muitas vezes vou esquecer clicar em "Check Out for Edit".